# gem install openssl conflict?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

When I run `gem install bundler` I get this error. How do I fix it?

```
gem install bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        dlopen(.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - .rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: There are many known issues around this when you have multiple ruby versions.  Please see this post https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353